# @media in bluehost is being commented out

Tags: css, responsive

Bluehost which is hosting my WordPress files, doesn't seem to be reading my `@media` code.

Everything starting with an `@` symbol is *greyed out* and is not being read at all which means my site is currently completely unresponsive.

Anyone know why or how to fix this?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to talk to Bluehost about this

Answer (score 0):

Media queries are not used by default. They are only used if the screen's size matches one of the conditions. For example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1000px){ }
```

Will only trigger if your screen size is below 1000px wide. If you are visiting the page and your screen is larger than this, the browser will show this query as grayed out, since it's not being used.

But if for any reason your responsive CSS file is not being loaded, I suggest you add it to the bottom of your `style.css` file. This way it will be loaded for sure.

Comment: What @Jack said. You can change the screen size in Firefox (for testing) via Ctrl+M. Then use the developer tools to see the css files loaded.